# How can I configure a vanilla virtualbox host and docker to use the same virtual network?

Tags: docker, virtualbox, nat

I'm using docker with elubow/cassandra and can start 3 machines.
I have a virtualbox ubuntu guest with cassandra installed and I want it to be the base node. The three docker machines should be seeds to the vbox instance.

Without using bridged networking (giving IPs on the physical network) I want to have the ubuntu guest see the other cassandra nodes, and using port forwards, allow my host machine to connect to certain ports on ubuntu.

I can create the NAT network in vbox, and can create a similar one with docker network create, but its not the same network, and docker doesnt seem to know about the one created in vbox or vice-versa. How can I make all these guests use the same NAT network?

Comment: What OS is the host?

Comment: my host machine is osx

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can directly attach a VirtualBox VM to the Docker for Mac VM as they use different virtualisation sub systems.

To get them close (network wise) you can add a ["Host-only"](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly) adapter to the Cassandra VM. This will also create a new "loopback" interface on the VM host.

Your mac can be assigned an IP of 192.168.30.1 and your VM can be assigned 192.168.30.2.

The containers will be able to directly access the VM on 192.168.30.2 without mapping ports and the VM can connect directly to the Docker mapped ports on 192.168.30.1.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `pipework` https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework.

Refer https://github.com/opensdcp/opensdcp-infrastructure for more informations, this needs connection between VM and br0 bridge.

I have only tested this on Linux (Debian 9, Alpine Linux and Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop) however.